# Why IntEnum doesn't care if I use a tuple?

Tags: python, enums

Have noticed someone write an enum like this:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Animal(IntEnum):
    dog = 1,
    cat = 2
```

And I thought it was a mistake which would make a runtime error because dog's value was actually a tuple.  To my surprise it works, and `Animal.dog.value == 1`.

This works:

```
class Potato(IntEnum):
    spud = ()
```

with the empty tuple being converted to integer 0 somehow (possibly argument splatting to a call to `int`?).

This doesn't work though:

```
class Potato(IntEnum):
    spud = []
```

We get `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`.

I see this on both python3 and the enum34 backport to python 2.

**How/why `IntEnum` or his metaclass implicitly converts tuples to integers?**

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it looks like the values are converted to tuple internally:  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/enum.py#l141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to look into `enum.py` to understand what happens. In fact, when you enter a value **that is not a tuple**, it is converted to `(value,)`, and if a tuple it is left unchanged. Then for a `IntEnum` the actual value is computed with `int(*args)`.

Ok, now what happens :

- if you give a simple int : `int(10) = 10`, all is fine
- if you give a tuple containing a single int : conversion leads to same case
- if you give a list : `int([...])` gives an error
- if you give a tuple (string_value, base) example `('1f', 16)` : you correctly get 31 !

  ```
  >>> class Animal(IntEnum):
      dog = '1F', 16
      cat = 5

  >>> Animal.dog.value
  31
  ```

But I could not find any trace of it in module documentation, and I thing it must be considered as an implementation detail ...

Comment: fun!  fortunately you can not trick the `@enum.unique` decorator by abusing this ..

Answer (score 1):

To support `__new__` and `__init__` methods, your values are converted to tuples and passed as arguments to the `__init__` or `__new__` method to produce the values of the enum. To support multiple arguments, any existing tuples are not converted.

In [*Allowed members and attributes of enumerations*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations) it states:

> Note: if your enumeration defines `__new__()` and/or `__init__()` then whatever value(s) were given to the enum member will be passed into those methods. See `Planet` for an example.

And in the [*Planet* example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet):

> If `__new__()` or `__init__()` is defined the value of the enum member will be passed to those methods.

For your case then, this happens:

- Single non-tuple values are converted to a tuple, so `2` becomes `(2,)`
- Tuple values are left untouched, so `1,` or `()` stay tuples.

after which the `int.__new__` method is called as `int.__new__(*args)`.

Now what happens:

- `int(1,)` is `1`.
- `int(2,)` is `2`.
- `int()` is `0`.

You can extend this to support arbitrary base integers:

```
>>> class BasesOfTenEnum(IntEnum):
...     octal = '10', 8
...     decimal = '10', 10
...     hexadecimal = '10', 16
... 
>>> list(BasesOfTenEnum)
[<BasesOfTenEnum.octal: 8>, <BasesOfTenEnum.decimal: 10>, <BasesOfTenEnum.hexadecimal: 16>]
```

As an interesting side note, to make matters just a little more complicated, if you mix in `tuple` with `Enum`, the tuple value is wrapped in another tuple so you can still pass it to `tuple.__new__` as a single argument.